# How to avoid Error :‘sum’ not meaningful for factors?

Tags: r

I experiencesome issues recently with a function I wrote to get unsampled google analytics data:

Original function:

```
library(RGA)



brows<-get_ga(profile.id="",
          start.date= "2015-08-20", 
          end.date= "2015-08-23",
          metrics = "ga:sessions", 
          dimensions = "ga:browser,ga:date", 
          sort="ga:date",
          filters="ga:browser==Safari,ga:browser==Chrome,ga:browser==Internet Explorer,ga:browser==Firefox",
          segment=NULL,
          start = 1, 
          max = NULL)
```

That function is used to load data from via Google Api. There is no other way(with `R and library(RGA)`) to load data into R. However, If the time range of your query extends certain threshold Google provides only `sampled Data`. Therefore, I adjusted the function by splitting the time range into smaller peaces which are then summed up (in order to avoid that particular threshold)

Modified function:

```
dates <- seq(as.Date("2015-08-20"), as.Date("2015-08-23"), by = "days")

modified <- aggregate(. ~date, FUN = sum,
data = do.call(rbind, lapply(dates,
function(date) {get_ga(profile.id = "", 
                   start.date = date, 
                   end.date = date,
                   metrics = "ga:sessions",
                   dimensions = "ga:browser,ga:date",
                   sort="ga:date",
                   filters="ga:browser==Safari,ga:browser==Chrome,ga:browser==Internet Explorer,ga:browser==Firefox",
                   segment=NULL,
                   start = NULL, 
                   max = NULL)})))
```

In order to avoid sampled data the modified function aggregates data by day. It works fine. Now I get the `error`

```
Error in Summary.factor(1:4, na.rm = FALSE) : 
  ‘sum’ not meaningful for factors
```

I understand that somewhere there must be a factor. However, I'm not very sure where to expand my `aggregate` function in order to `as.numeric`.

Comment: From where comes function `get_ga`?

Comment: @ Pascal...sorry the most important question library(RGA)

Comment: After loading the data from GA, save it somewhere (let's say `res`). Then run `indx <- sapply(res, is.numeric)` and then do `aggregate(. ~date, res[c("date", names(res)[indx])], sum)`

Comment: @ David thank you for the suggestion. However, the problem is with loading the GA data, which is usually done by the `modified`function itself.

Comment: So can't you modify that function accordingly? I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: I can modify the function accordingly. However I cant load the GA data before. I use the `modiefied` function to load the `unsampled`data from GA. There is no other way to load `unsamped`data to R. If I would have the possibility to load the `unsampled` GA data before, there is no need to use the function.

Comment: I still don't understand what you mean. Can you show a better example why can't you modify the function, what is your input and what is the desired output?